# Cannot add SQL Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, derby, composite-primary-key

I have two tables. One is called BooksRead, one is called Authors. Authors has a Primary Key of BOTH author_last_name and author_first_name.

I'm using Netbeans IDE.

I want to alter table BooksRead, which also has columns author_last_name and author_first_name, to reference Authors as Foreign Keys.

```
ALTER TABLE BooksRead
ADD FOREIGN KEY(AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME) 
REFERENCES AUTHORS(AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME);
```

I've tried to do this many different ways--including adding/naming a CONSTRAINT--but always get the same error:

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState X0Y45] Foreign key constraint 'SQL170903182055780' cannot be added to or enabled on table BOOKSREAD because one or more foreign keys do not have matching referenced keys.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Is it Derby?

Comment: Also, sounds like your `BooksRead` table has data that violates the foreign key constraint, ie there are no matching records in `Authors`

Comment: Java DB, Apache Derby.

Comment: That's the part that's puzzling--Authors' Primary Key is author_last_name and author_first_name. It should work.

Comment: It's not puzzling at all. This is what can happen when you start adding data before constraints.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. You elicited two guesses (that should have been this comment.) Anyway this is a faq. There's a [derby answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8918957/3404097) with your error & causes but not what turned out to be your problem; but there are lists to troubleshoot in answers for sql generally & other sqls.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `BooksRead` table has data that violates the foreign key constraint, ie there are no matching records in `Authors`.

Find and fix the records before adding the constraint

```
SELECT br.*
FROM BooksRead br
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM AUTHORS a
  WHERE a.AUTHOR_LAST_NAME = br.AUTHOR_LAST_NAME
  AND a.AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME = br.AUTHOR_FIRST_NAME
)
```

That will give you a list of `BooksRead` rows not having a matching `AUTHOR`. You can either

- Delete those rows
- Add the relevant author details to `AUTHORS`, or
- Perhaps the author details in `BooksRead` have typos or leading / trailing whitespace. Fix the author details in the `BooksRead` row to match records in `AUTHORS`

Comment: It was one entry in the AUTHORS table that had a space between -- "R. R. Martin"  --that threw it off. It was supposed to have "R.R. Martin". So, you were right: it was what happened when you add data before constraints. Thanks!

Comment: @beh1 now would be a good time to normalise your data and use numeric IDs in the `AUTHORS` table and reference those instead of the composite key

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the existing data on the child table,exists on the parent as  a primary key